# asp textbox allow only letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I found a way allowing only numbers:

button:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="LabelValue" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" runat="server" Text=''></asp:TextBox>
```

JS

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;    
   return true;
}
```

Ca we modify above function little bit which allows only letters and numbers for asp textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated function would be:

```
function isAlphaNumericKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        console.log("false");
        return false;
    }
    console.log("true");
    return true;
}
```

I also have it in a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcart/s0py4bfs/) for you if you want to play with it first.  I just used a textfield but its the same thing

i actually considered making it a couple methods for code clarity but didnt want to go overboard.

Comment: pls, change the function name, people may confuse.